# I keep getting the following error in django: "UnboundLocalError at /myapp/"

Tags: python, django, local-variables

I am facing this error in django python:

"UnboundLocalError at /myapp/" 
local variable 'album' referenced before assignment

I Created a class in models.py file and import in views but facing this error

Here is complete code of both files:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models

class album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist+'--'+self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import album

def myapp(request):
   all_albums = album.objects.all()
   title = album.artist
   html = ''
   for album in all_albums:
      url = '/myapp/' + str(album.id) + '/'
      html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a><br>'
   return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: You are using the `album` variable multiple times. Once as a model, and other times as an instance. Model names should ideally be CamelCased.

Comment: Can you please explain how to write Model code in CamelCased ?

Comment: You just change `class album(models.Model):` to `class Album(models.Model):` as described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320036/i-keep-getting-the-following-error-in-django-unboundlocalerror-at-myapp#answer-45320209). But that alone won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy this totally and paste in your view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import album

def myapp(request):
   all_albums = album.objects.all()
   html = ''
   for al in all_albums:
      url = '/myapp/' + str(al.id) + '/'
      html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + al.artist + '</a><br>'
   return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

Move title inside the loop and better use loop variable name not like model

```
html = ''
for album_data in all_albums:
    url = '/myapp/' + str(album_data.id) + '/'
    title = album_data.artist
    html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a><br>'
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: The same error? if not show, and may be it good show full new code

Answer (score 1):

Change the view like this,

```
def myapp(request):
    all_albums = album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in all_albums:
       url = '/myapp/' + str(album.id) + '/'
       html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + album.artist + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `album` name for multiple variables, once as a model, and other times as an instance. Model names should ideally be CamelCased. After correcting the model name, move the `title` variable assignment inside the `for` loop. Only doing the latter would solve your problem for now, but if you stick to the styling guidelines ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) you wouldn't face such issues in the future.

**models.py**

```
...
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
...
```

**views.py**

```
...
from .models import Album

def myapp(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for album in all_albums:
        title = album.artist
        url = '/myapp/' + str(album.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a><br>'
...
```

Comment: @habib You need to post a full stacktrace then. Also, if you've updated your code with suggested changes, edit your question to add the updated code.